# Why am I getting a different result when using Anaconda_Jupyter versus Ubuntu_ipython (and why the answer of Jupyter isn't correct)?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I manually chose a singular matrix (therefore not invertible) and tested the inverse and determinant of it using both Anaconda_Jupyter and Ubuntu_ipython. Here's the odd result:

Anaconda_Jupyter:

[When using Anaconda_Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcjiq.png)

Ubuntu_ipython:

[When using Ubuntu_ipython](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytslz.png)

So as you can see the answer that I am getting when using Jupyter notebook isn't correct. Why is that?

Comment: Please paste your code in the question, and don't use images!